# One valve for hose spigot and irrigation?

Tags: plumbing

I have a section of galvanized in my water line still. I am going to replace it with copper. The horizontal galvanized and old red valve goes to a hose bib. The horizontal copper and ball valve goes to my irrigation valve box. Is there any reason why I can't just put in a tee left of the bonding clamp and bleed so I have just one valve?

I live in Denver and shutdown my irrigation and my hose spigots at the same time in the fall. So I would have no need to have one of them on and the other off. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only potential problem would be lower maximum flow to the irrigation system when the hose is in use because both would be fed by a single pipe instead of the two in use now.  But eyeballing the pipe sizes and configuration, that seems unlikely:  the length of pipe feeding both is fairly short; and you are presumably ok with the existing hose flow through the narrow galvanized pipe, and can always throttle it down to the same level after the change if need be.

Comment: The two are never on at the same time, so pressure for the sprinklers wouldn't be an issue. Would there be any issues with the irrigation's pressure vacuum breaker being impacted and not sealing correctly when turning the system on in the spring?

Comment: I don’t see why.  BTW, the hose Bibb should have a vac breaker too.